# Opening up the Java Console on Firefox 6 with Red Hat Linux

Tags: java, firefox, console, redhat

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to start the java console through firefox with Redhat Linux.

Per: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/console.html . I am told to open up the console via the task bar or by configuring it to startup whenever  java plugin is loaded.  For the first one, I don't seem to see any java application process in any sort of task bar for Red Hat Linux and therefore can't open the console manually.  Secondly, modifying the settings doesn't seem to work either as I have set the default to open the Java Console through the jconsole application in my JRE's bin folder.

My question is: Is there any other way to open the java console via firefox?  Is there a URL command that will open up the java console?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Java console 6.0.27 is incompatible with firefox 6.0.1](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/870013?s=Java%20console&as=s), so my guess is that Firefox disabled your java console extension on startup. Check your add-ons for what's enabled and disabled. Odds are you'll need to upgrade Java and/or your Java Console extension.

Comment: Well I know that the console works.  I sometimes can get the console to open if I get a Security exception that isn't a runtime permission exception.  I'm really looking for a way to open the java console manually.  I have seen the shortcut Shift-Ctrl-O but that was for a previous version and doesn't seem to work for the current one.